# Upload image in json (compress in base64) from android to web service php

Tags: php, android, json, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to upload an image(draw compressed in base64) as a JSONObject from android to web service using PHP. I tried to use HttpURLConnection with method post.

My code, in android.

```
try {

            JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
            params.put("nombre", name);
            params.put("img", imgBase64);

            Log.d("params", params.toString());


            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");



            BufferedOutputStream BuffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(BuffOut, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(params.toString());
            writer.close();
            BuffOut.close();


            //open
            conn.connect();

            //do somehting with response
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader buffr = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = buffr.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                Log.d("leer", sb.toString());
                buffr.close();
                conn.disconnect();

                return sb.toString();

            } else {
                Log.d("err","false : " + responseCode);
                return "false : " + responseCode;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return " Exception JSON: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return " IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return " UnsupportedEncodingException: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            return " ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return " MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return " Exception IO: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return " Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
```

In Logcat I have an error like: ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

In server side, php I have:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])&&!empty($_POST['img'])){
         echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'msg' => "hi ".$_POST['nombre']. " img ".$_POST['img']));
    }
 }
```

Comment: `BufferedWriter reader ` ??? you think your naming is fine?

Comment: Post the LogCat as we want to see that exception.

Comment: `BufferedOutputStream inB`  In ? In?

Comment: `ProtocolException` ? We cannot see the protocol you use. Please show the value of `urlServer`;

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])&&!empty($_POST['img']))` You cannot use that as you post json. Not parameters. This has been said before!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't demand on specific feature or have some constraint I would recommend using volley for network handling [volley home page](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)